# How to get Lowest value of each group in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get lowest value of each group from two table

**Table Are Below**

```
    Table 1                         Table 2         
|   GPN |   Amt |           |   GPN |   Date        |
|   A   |   10  |           |   A   |   2016-09-10  |
|   A   |   15  |           |   A   |   2016-09-18  |
|   A   |   20  |           |   B   |   2016-09-10  |
|   A   |   25  |           |   B   |   2016-09-11  |
|   A   |   30  |           |   B   |   2016-09-12  |
|   B   |   20  |           |   C   |   2016-10-12  |
|   B   |   40  |           |   C   |   2016-10-13  |
|   B   |   60  |           |   C   |   2016-10-14  |
|   B   |   80  |           |   D   |   2016-09-10  |
|   B   |   100 |           |   D   |   2016-10-13  |
|   C   |   3   |                           
|   C   |   6   |                           
|   C   |   9   |                           
|   C   |   12  |                           
|   C   |   15  |                           
|   D   |   7   |                           
|   D   |   10  |                           
|   D   |   13  |                           
|   D   |   16  |                           
|   D   |   19  |                           
|   D   |   22  |
```

How i want that value

For Example

Date = 2016-09-10,

On That how many GPN are there so i have to get every GPN's Lowest Amt

So Result Will be like this

```
    Result          
|   GPN |   Amt |
|   A   |   10  |
|   B   |   20  |
|   D   |   7   |
```

I have tried by using **ASC LIMIT 1** so obviously it will show only one raw but but i have no idea how to do that.

and i did it with php loop but i am looking if it is possible in mysql query so that will awesome.

Comment: By using the `MIN()` aggregate function, and a `GROUP BY` clause - [MySQL Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html)

Comment: Please double-check your expected result

Comment: Sorry @1000111 i edited it

Comment: I think your table structure is probably incorrect -- what is the relation between Table1 and Table2?  It doesn't look like there is a meaningful one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inner join and group by

```
select table1.GPN, min(table2.Amt) 
from table1 
inner join table2 on table1.GPN= table2.GPN
where date(table2.date )  = str_to_date('2016-09-10', '%Y-%m-%d') 
group by table1.GPN
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'table 2 on table1.GPN= table2.GPN
and date(table2.date )  = str_to_date('2016-0' at line 3

Comment: line1 there is "table1.Amt" and second is line 3 table 2 should be table2 then it works

Comment: Thanks you so much

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic [aggregate function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) query.

```
SELECT T1.GPN, MIN(Amt) FROM Table1 T1 INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.GPN = T2.GPN GROUP BY T1.GPN WHERE T2.Date = ?
```

Comment: It is showing me error i am trying to look but not getting error

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE T2.Date = '2016-09-10' LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

Comment: SELECT T1.GPN, MIN(T1.Amt) as Amount FROM Table1 T1 INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.GPN = T2.GPN WHERE T2.Date = '2016-09-10' GROUP BY T1.GPN